# Micronaut reload source changes intellj idea

Tags: intellij-idea, micronaut, hot-reload

I am starting with micronaut framework and intellj idea

In other proyects when i save a chance in the source Code, the debugging app auto update.

But when i do It in micronaut project i need stop and restart for achieve get the Code

It s very slow cicle, any solución?

Comment: See also https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/blob/2.3.x/src/main/docs/guide/cli/reloading/automaticRestart.adoc.

Comment: See also https://docs.micronaut.io/2.3.0/guide/index.html#reloading.

Comment: "Micronaut uses annotation processors and some other build time magic which can make hot swapping impossible." - That isn't really true.  We do have support for JRebel.

Comment: @CrazyCoder When you deleted your comment about hot swapping being impossible you also deleted a link to some reloading thing that I am interested in but I don't know how to view deleted comments.  Would you share that link again?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown the links was to http://dcevm.github.io/.